# How to derive new column based on condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table.

[image: img]

I wish to write a SQL query based on these conditions: where stage is Screening and status is min of data (its date actually) of status =(Selected /  Rejected / Dropped) as Interview date

Comment: your problem description not much clear ,could you please describe what you need as a output and of-course SO does not prefer image as a sample data

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: sorry for not being clear , I use SQL sever .
I have only 1 table which have columns till data ( actually date ) . i need separate derived column in same table called as Interview table   .

Condition is Stage is screening and status in ( Rejected , dropped , Selected ) and data (actually date) is min of Selected /Rejected/dropped

Comment: On Stack Overflow, "please help me with writing a query" often means "write the query for me", and that is clearly the case here. This sort of approach is not always well received, because readers will want to know why you have not tried anything. Of course, if you _have_ tried something, please add it into your question, so readers can be assured that you want to learn this for yourself. Thanks!

Comment: In your sample data, every `ID` has a Screening row as it's earliest date. If that's always the case, is this not just "select the min date from all rows for the same ID and make that the interview date"? If not, please consider giving us more representative data.

Comment: from what I have understand, this should do the trick: `select stage, status, data, min(data) over(partition by stage) from table
    where stage = 'Screening' and status in ('Selected', 'Rejected', 'Dropped')` it will omit all rows that do not match with your condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    t1.stage, t1.status, t2.data 
from 
    table as t1 
inner join
    (select 
         stage, min(data) as data 
     from 
         table 
     group by 
         stage) as t2 on t1.stage = t2.stage and t1.data = t2.data
```

Comment: just for completeness: You've forgot the filter in your query :-)